# How to style drupal twitter block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-8

I'm trying to modify some div's classes inside an `iframe` using my own css and change the Twitter Block | Drupal 8 look. But, I've faced a lot of error such as `$ is not a function` etc....I thought that my `js` was loaded too fast (before my `jquery.js`), however, I inspected the elements and everything should be working. (No errors now)

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" class="twetter-timeline" >
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <div class="timeline-Viewport">
          <ol class="timeline-TweetList">
             <li></li>
          </ol>
       </div>
     </body>
   </html>
 </iframe>
```

Note: I don't have control on the `iframe` it's not in my own code.

**JS**

```
  (function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
   Drupal.behaviors.yourbehavior = {
   attach: function (context, settings) {

       $('iframe').load( function() {
    $('#twitter-wwidget-0').contents().find("body")
  .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .timeline-Widget{color:red;}   </style>"));
});


   }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

No error but it doesn't work...so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE:
I also tried this code, but didn't work either.

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('hello');
    $('#twitter-widget-0').css('width', '100px');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Is the iframe's contents on your domain, or Twitter's? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: hey @ceejayoz  it is on my domain ..thanks for asking

Comment: @ceejayoz any idea =/?

Comment: Your code seems clean, but can you try replacing `$` with `jQuery` in your code.

Comment: @kisanme you mean from my last function? I mean my last update?

Comment: Didn't work.  I can see the `Hello` but the `width` is not changing at all

Comment: @ArielMaduro was changing from `$` to `jQuery` the one who made to print `hello`?

Comment: @kisanme there is an extra 50 points for the answer.  I know there are other way to get a twitter widget on my page, but I am really curious on why I can't hit the `<iframe>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) access control prevents the containing document from modifying (or even knowing about) the contents of an `iframe` if its contents are sourced from a different domain than that of the containing document. There are mechanisms (such as [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)) for getting around this but they require cooperation between the inside and outside of the `iframe`.

In the case of Twitter, they have [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets) on how to adjust the styling of Twitter post and feed embeds. (It looks like Twitter restricts styling to a dark or light theme, width, alignment, and link color.)

Comment: Also the OP should, obligatory, change the methodology of solving or covering the requirements. I suggest to use [REST APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) of twitter.

Comment: @sємsєм I will take a look to the above links! but I really would like to know why I couldn't hit the `<iframe>` even within my own domain.

Comment: @ArielMaduro Was it really the same domain (and port and protocol)? `www.example.com` and `example.com` are considered different domains. If they really are the same domain, something like `$($('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document)` should get you the document inside the `iframe` as a jQuery object. (jQuery can't jump the boundary on its own.) Something like `$('#someId', $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document)` should get you a particular element by ID relative to the `iframe`'d document.

Comment: @Ouroborus do you think that there is another way to get twitter feed horizontally???

Comment: @ArielMaduro I imagine there are several ways. Integrating them into Drupal may be the challenging part of the task.

Comment: @Ouroborus Yes I know! that is the challenge here.  This is what I am trying to do: http://www.jjay.cuny.edu/ at the bottom, there are twitter feed.  I THINK they might be using `json` (not 100% sure)

Comment: @ArielMaduro My experience is either your server or another service ([Tint](https://www.tintup.com/) is one that I've worked with which supports custom formatting) would need to access one of [Twitter's APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation), gathering and caching the data it needs. From there, you're free to reformat that data (within Twitter's Terms of Use) and re-serve it to your page. Looking at the network traffic for the page url you provided it appears that John Jay College is doing exactly this, using their own server to proxy, modify, and re-serve Twitter API feeds.